# Did Wil talk to Amberle after she became the Elcrys?

Tags: shannara, elfstones-of-shannara

At the ending of *Elfstones of Shannara*, Wil did not touch the new Elcrys formed from Amberle and the seed of the old Elcrys. Touching the Elcrys should have allowed them to say goodbye.

Comment: Hi.  Welcome!  Could you clarify your question a bit?  You ask whether Wil talked to Amberle after she became the Ellcrys, but you then go on to describe the scene at the end, where he does not talk to her nor touch her.  What do you really want to know?

Comment: Actually, he said one word.  He whispered, "Amberle..."  That is clear in the text though, so probably doesn't answer what you are trying to ask.